# Basic Expansion

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

I know this is probably easy but how would I multiply out

$$(z-(5+i))(z-(5-i))$$

Would I multiply inside both brackets by the "-" then the z part?

Thanks

Comment: Um, there's no multiplication _inside_ any of the brackets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the "FOIL" method of expansion:

$(z-(5+i))(z-(5-i))$

$z^2-z(5+i)-z(5-i)+(5+i)(5-i)$

$z^2-10z+26$.

That's all!

Comment: Except you seem to be doing FIOL rather than FOIL. Why do people go around remembering that stupid acronym when they are not even writing the terms in the order it mandates?

Answer (score 2):

I would rewrite to $((z-5)-i)((z-5)+i)=(z-5)^2-i^2=(z-5)^2+1$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $$(A-B)(A-C) = A^2-AC-BA+CB$$